# Construct a list of powers in fewest multiplications

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-optimization

Let $A$ be some object in a space with a notion of associative multiplication, eg., imagine that $A$ is a square matrix. Here is my question: given some set of positive integers $S=\{s_1,...,s_n\}$, how do we compute each of the powers $\{A^{s_1}, A^{s_2},...,A^{s_n}\}$ using the fewest possible number of multiplications?

For example, consider $S=\{2,3,6\}$. Then we need three multiplications in total:

```
A2 = A*A
A3 = A2*A
A6 = A3*A3
```

Note that this is more efficient than a naive binary expansion of the members of $S$, since we can bypass $A^4$. Having sorted $S$ in ascending order, I guess this problem can be reduced to the recursive step: what is the fewest number of multiplications required to produce $A^{s_n}$ given cached copies of $\{A^{s_1}, A^{s_2},...,A^{s_{n-1}}\}$? This problem seems related to the [change making problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem).

Note: I am most interested in an algorithm that tells me what to multiply with what.

Comment: This needs to pre-elaborate a list of optimal arrangements of sumands, and then apply them

Comment: I think you mean to square $A3$ instead of multiplication with $A2$

Comment: @MartinRubey thanks, fixed.

Comment: Do you allow multiplicative inverses? For example $A7=A8\cdot (A-1)$?

Comment: looks equivalent to  [addition-sequence problem](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/10.1137/0210047) which is NP-complete.

Comment: @achillehui indeed, looks the same. Thanks.

Comment: @Xpw good question, had not thought about it ... for me the answer is no, but in cases where division is the same price or cheaper than multiplication, that would be relevant.